# Openlayers 3 Select two features from two different layers at same position

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a layer with markers and one layer with polylines. The markers are at the end of the polylines. I like to drag any marker synchronous with the end (overapping) of the polyline.

```
var features = new ol.Collection();
var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}),style:styles});
featureOverlay.setMap(map);

var markers = new ol.Collection();
var markerOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({source: new ol.source.Vector({features: markers}),style:styles});
markerOverlay.setMap(map);

var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({features: features});
map.addInteraction(modify);


var modifyn = new ol.interaction.Modify({features: markers});
map.addInteraction(modifyn);
```

It's not working synchronous. I have to drag the end of the polyline and the marker separate.

How can I drag both at the same time?

Thanks for helping!
Andreas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

I collect all features at the mouse position in realtime and save them in a collection. This collection is the feature in modify.

Cheers!

```
var allFeaturesAtPixel = new ol.Collection();
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({features: allFeaturesAtPixel});
map.addInteraction(modify);

map.on('pointermove', function (evt) 
{
 allFeaturesAtPixel.clear();
 map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {allFeaturesAtPixel.push(feature);});
});
```